# How do I cut a square out of a numpy array and create an array out of that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to basically do this:

```
data = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
print(data)
>> [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

Then it would cut it somehow, and I would end up with this

```
[[6 7 8]
[11 12 13]
[16 17 18]]
```

I tried using colons but I have no idea how they work, (like data = data(1:3, 4:5))

Comment: This is just an extension of basic Python list indexing `alist[1:10]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track; just use brackets for array subscripting and the same indices for both dimensions of the array:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
print(data)

print(data[1:4, 1:4])
```

outputs

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

[[ 6  7  8]
 [11 12 13]
 [16 17 18]]
```